# Files can't provide quoted paths to command line programs

Tags: windows-10, git-bash

As some of you may know when you open a file with a program, what's happening is the file path of the file is supplied to the program as an argument. What's happening is for some reason Windows is unable to provide quoted paths to these programs causing inability to open the said files.

For example, C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe will give an error in the command prompt as there is space between the path. 
So the correct format to access this file would be to quote it like this: "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe". Which is what's not happening here.

Due to this, I'm unable to open .sh files directly and a couple of other things.

What could be causing this problem? This has been this way ever since I updated Git Windows to 2.5.0 (the latest version), I uninstalled it and installed the old version but the problem stayed. So no use. Any solutions or ideas on what might be causing this problem? I even ran SFC /Scannow, also didn't help.